# How do I make an img fill an internal-container for mobile website?

Tags: css, image, mobile, containers, responsive

I am quite new to developing a website, however, using the underscores theme I have made a website for my company with css - it works find but I am not able to make it mobile-friendly. As you can see on a desktop view, there are two internal-containers with images on it fitting perfectly: https://www.bailiwicklegal.com.au/homepage/

When viewing on mobile however, these images in both containers are compressed and does not fill up the width of the screen. Not only is this happening on the homepage but also with other images on the following pages if you click either of the two containers on the landing page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Above is the viewport I am using

```
img {
height: auto;
/* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
max-width: 100%;
/* Adhere to container width. */
```

}

Above is the css for img on my style sheet generally 
Below is the css for the internal-container and

```
.circle-container {
width:22%;
display:inline-block;
margin:0 15px 30px 15px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;
```

}

Below is my css for the media querie

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 991px) {
.internal-container {max-width:100%;padding:0 20px;}
.internal-container 
.circle-container {display:block; width:100%; margin: 0 auto;}
.internal-container h1 {max-width:100%;}
body.single-post 
.internal-container img {display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto; max-height:100%;}
.narrow-width {max-width:100%;}
header .secondary, header .col-50 {display:none;}
header .col-25 {max-width:100%;padding:0 0 0 20px;}
.logo img {max-width: 100% ; display:block;}
h1.intro {font-size:25px;}
h1.intro, .intro-statement {width:100%;padding:0 20px;}
.circle-container {display:block;margin:0;}
.circle-container h2 {display:block; text-align:center;padding:0;margin: 20px 0;}
.home-circle, .home-circle:before  {max-width:100%; max-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle}
.home-circle:hover span {display:block;}
.intro-statement {font-size:16px;}
.intro-statement h3 {font-size:24px;}
footer .col-50 {width:100%;padding:20px;}
.news-container span {float:left;}
.news-container .col-50 {line-height:2;padding:10px 20px;}
.news-container h3 {width:100%;}
.col-people img {display:block;float:none;margin:0 20px;}
.col-news {width:100%;}
footer .doyles {float:none;margin:0;display:block;}
.footer-nav {text-align:center !important;}
.copyright 
.bk-overlay {display:none;}
.copyright 
.col-50 {float:none;margin:0;display:block;}
.footer-links {display:none;}
.contact-text {float:none;margin:0;display:block;}
 }}
```

It would mean a lot if you can help me finish off the final touches of the mobile website! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove the inline style for `circle-container`. Then change the style of `circle-container` like so

```
.circle-container{
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:unset !important
}
```

Then change the viewport like this.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 991px){
  .circle-container{
     width:50%;
     margin:0 auto;
  }
}
```

Lastly, add an additional code for a smaller screen

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 410px){
    .circle-container{
      width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

This is definitely not a good way, but it will work for now. Try to change you code to make it more responsive :))

Comment: I've edited that for circle-container, however, it has done no effects on the mobile website and have just moved around the images on the desktop view.

What do I change display:inline-block; to? thank you!

Comment: Did you change the inline style? Cause the inline style has more priority than the external one. Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://imgur.com/5Md8Zv4

Comment: yes, exactly that ! What did you put down for that to happen? I know I need to get rid of the inline style but I just don't know what to replace it with. If you could send the css for what you did to get that, that would be amazing.

Comment: Firstly, remove the inline css from the `<div class="circle-container">...` because that will get in our way. I will edit the answer.